# How to custom-file-label using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, django-templates

I have a simple `upload.html` page which require the image to upload. When I upload  the image, it displays the image name in `console` but it does not change the `label` . This is the result when I upload image :

[image: Result]

This is my code:

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="display-3 my-2 text-center">Breast Cancer Prediction</div>
    <hr />
    {% if image_class %}
    <div class="display-4 my-2 text-center">
        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <p>Class : {{ image_class.class }}</p>
            Confidence: {{ image_class.confidence }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="row mb-6">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form action="" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
                {{ searchForm.hidden_tag() }}
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ searchForm.mrn.label() }}
                        {{ searchForm.mrn(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ searchForm.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
    {% if messages %}
    {% for category, message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ category }} alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        {{ message }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    <div class="row mb-5">
        <div class="col-md-6 m-auto mb-5">
            <!-- Name here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 pt">
            <!-- Add here -->
            {% if form %}
            <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.picture.label(class="custom-file-label", for="picture") }}
                    {{ form.picture(class="file custom-file-input") }}
                    {% if form.picture.errors %}
                    {% for error in form.picture.errors %}
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span></br>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="mt-4 text-center">
                    {{ form.submit2(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
                </div>
            </form>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#picture').change(function(e) {
        var filename = e.target.files[0].name;
        $('.custom-file-label').text(filename)
    });

    function displayfilename() {
        $('#picture').trigger('change');
    }
    </script>
    {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: What template engine are you using? It also seems like your using a CSS library. I assume Bootstrap 4 with the jQuery JavaScript library.

Comment: @JensIngels yes

Comment: hi where is this `$('.custom-file-label')` in your dom ?

Comment: @Swati here `{{ form.picture.label(class="custom-file-label", for="picture") }}`

Comment: Hi put console inside your event handler see if that gets called  because your code looks ok to me .

Comment: on console it display but didn't change lable.